# Construct a filepath for a different operating system in Python

Tags: python, linux, windows, filepath

How can I use python to construct a path intended for a different operating system than the one the script is running on?

E.g.  I am running a script on Linux in which I want to construct the Windows path

```
winPath = os.path.join(winRoot, dir, subdir) #doesn't work when script is run on linux
```

Comment: Surely, there is no `winRoot` on Linux. On linux, the root of the file system is `"/"`.

Comment: @DYZ, sorry for the typo.  Yes, there is no windows root on Linux; on linux the root of the file system is "/".  We are in absolute agreement there.  And yet, on linux, I want to construct a windows filepath.  In this script, winRoot is hard-coded as "c:"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Check this doc page](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html)

Import the ntpath module to generate windows paths.

```
winPath = os.join.path(winRoot, dir, subdir)
```

becomes

```
winPath = ntpath.join(winRoot, dir, subdir)
```